# how to add custom tags in yuidoc

Tags: javascript, yui, yuidoc

I need to add some custom plugins like @date and @author in a javascript project that I am working on.

WE are using yuidoc for the documentation purpose.

But there are two cases here

1> @data tag is not there in yuidoc

2> @author tag is there but doesn't display in the docs

This is a list of the tags available

http://yui.github.io/yuidoc/syntax/

How do I make these tags show up in my documentation?

Is there a way I can add custom tags to show up in yuidoc?